# Need a solution for output from BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Im here with probably simple newbie question, but how do I make sure my code:

```
String number = scan.next();
BigDecimal number1 = new BigDecimal(number);
System.out.println(number1);
```

With input provided for example "00.001",
will output exactly "00.001"?

Because now it keeps printing me out 0.001 :/

Also i don't want to limit it only to this particular pattern, because this is in a for loop, and if I maybe input "00000.01" next time i also want it to be printed as "00000.01".

Comment: BigDecimal is intended to ensure precision of decimal values, not replication of formatting. Extra leading zeros have nothing to do with precision, that's just formatting. Only using strings would ensure retaining formatting like that.

Comment: Can I ask why? 00000.01 is just as precise as 0.01.. those zeros have no value

Comment: And if you really want to keep it that bad, create an object that encapsulates a String and a BigDecimal and just keep them together

Comment: @RobOhRob i found some exercise online and it says that the output must be exactly as the input, and im trying to figure it out.

Comment: Why don't you print `number` instead of `number1`. After all, it's a valid `BigDecimal`.